# Android: Other apps unable to access file inside my app

Tags: java, android, permissions

Other apps like Microsoft office, pdf viewer unable to open the files inside the "/file" directory of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been providing the Uri of the file through

```java
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

and I think that it was the wrong way of doing it, instead what you should be using is this

```java
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "/down.xls");
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
browserIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```